# Symfony2 "Parameter "" for route "" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL."

Tags: php, symfony, url, routes, yaml

I have this **routes** file:

```
indexRechercheZones:
    path:     /gestionzonestechniques
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceGestionEquipementsTechniquesBundle:GestionZonesTechniques:indexZonesTechnique }
    requirements:
    methods: GET

modifierZones:
    path:     /gestionzonestechniques/modifier/{nom}
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceGestionEquipementsTechniquesBundle:GestionZonesTechniques:modifierZonesTechnique }
    requirements:
    methods: GET

modifierZones_process:
    path:     /gestionzonestechniques/modifier/process/{nom}
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceGestionEquipementsTechniquesBundle:GestionZonesTechniques:modifierZonesTechnique }
    requirements:
    methods: POST
```

Now when I want to **proceed** to the `indexRechercheZones` route, an **error occured**:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Parameter "nom" for route "modifierZones" must match "[^/]++" (""
>   given) to generate a corresponding URL.") in
>   MySpaceGestion...sBundle:...:indexZonesTechniques.html.twig
>   at line 71.

In my twig line 71, I have this **code**:

```
<a href="{{ path('modifierZones', {'nom': zonetechnique.nom}) }}"><button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs">Modifier</button></a>
```

I think that is a regex problem, a problem with the url writing rule for symfony, but I don't how I can fix this error. I have tried some thing like adding this line in my route:

```
indexRechercheZones:
    path:     /gestionzonestechniques/
    defaults: { _controller: MySpaceGestionEquipementsTechniquesBundle:GestionZonesTechniques:indexZonesTechnique }
    requirements:
        nom:    \d+ 
    methods: GET
```

or like this at the requirements:

```
requirements:
    nom:    '[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/-\s.^]+'
```

But it does not match. Someone could help?

Thank you...

Comment: Well looks like your variable `zonetechnique.nom` is empty, so your parameter `nom` doesn't match any requirements (since your parameter isn't optional)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like @Coussinsky said, some `values` for your `field` "nom" are empty on your database.

You could make this **parameter** to `null` if you want, or just **change** the empty values on your database.

Comment: You could make some requirements in order to write url with regular expression like you mentionned in you answer `'[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/-\s.^]+'`. But look at the doc, yml have specific syntax.

Comment: How can I add the regex in my yaml file for the route if I want to mix it to the `{nom}`parameter? Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use annotation instead of .yml

```
#[Route('/gestionzonestechniques/{nom}', name: 'indexRechercheZones', requirements: ['nom' => '\d+'], methods: ['GET'])]
public function action(Request $request): JsonResponse
{}
```

And yes, **the error messages tells that $nom value does not match your pattern '\d+'.**

You need either control the value before to generate the route URI either to change the pattern to '.*'